# Continuous Fourier Transform with Python / Sympy (Analytical Solution)

Tags: python, sympy, continuous-fourier

I recently replaced Matlab with Python because I was real;y excited by Sympy.

But now I have the following problem:

I need a way to reliably calculate continuous fourier transforms with Python.  Sympy has problems with solutions including Diracs (Delta-functions) as they for example occur for trig-functions etc.

For example, if I try

```
fourier_transform(cos(x),x,v)
```

the output is `0` where it should be based on the Dirac delta function

Does anyone know, if this part of Sympy is going to be improved or if there is another way to analytically find fourier transforms with Python?

Thanks for answers or any advice in advance!

Comment: Can you give an example of an integral that doesn't work with SymPy?

Comment: yes, for example the fourier transform of simple trig functions like: fourier_transform(cos(x),x,v) --> gives 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no one is currently working on this, although [contributions are welcome](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Introduction-to-contributing).

Some advice I can give:

- If you set `noconds=False` in `fourier_transform()`, it will include conditions for which `0` is True:

  ```
  In [26]: fourier_transform(cos(t),t,x, noconds=False)
  Out[26]:
  ⎛   │                 ⎛ -ⅈ⋅π           2      ⎞│       │                 ⎛ ⅈ⋅π           2      ⎞│    ⎞
  ⎝0, │periodic_argument⎝ℯ    ⋅polar_lift (x), ∞⎠│ < π ∧ │periodic_argument⎝ℯ   ⋅polar_lift (x), ∞⎠│ < π⎠
  ```

  These conditions aren't very helpful except maybe to show that 0 isn't completely wrong.
- You can use `FourierTransform` to represent an unevaluated fourier transform. You can call `doit()` on it to evaluate it or `rewrite(Integral)` to get the integral form:

  ```
  In [28]: FourierTransform(cos(t),t,x).rewrite(Integral)
  Out[28]:
  ∞
  ⌠
  ⎮   -2⋅ⅈ⋅π⋅t⋅x
  ⎮  ℯ          ⋅cos(t) dt
  ⌡
  -∞
  ```

My best suggestion for now is to do the Fourier transforms that SymPy currently can't do manually by manipulating either `FourierTransform` objects or the integrals.